# Typescript: How to get subclass instance using parent get method

Tags: typescript, instance, subclass

Suppose I have a parent class with a static method that returns an instance,

```
abstract class AbstractManager {
    private static instance: AbstractManager;

    constructor() {
        AbstractManager.instance = this;
    }

    public static getInstance(): AbstractManager {
        return this.instance
    }

}
```

And I have a child class which extends the parent class,

```
class Manager extends AbstractManager {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

If I invoke `Manager.getInstance()` the return type is of the parent `AbstractManager`.

Is there a way to set up the parent `getInstance()` method so that it returns the child type instead?

Obviously, I can add a `getInstance()` to each of the children class returning or casting to the child type but should I have 100 subclasses then I'll need to write the method 100 times.

Although my knowledge of generics is limited, another solution I have attempted using generics is,

```
public static getInstance<T extends AbstractManager>(): T {
    return this.instance;
}
```

But this has caused the error `Type 'AbstractManager' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

Is it possible to set it up such that

```
Manager.getInstance() // is of type Manager not AbstractManager.
```

Or should I approach this problem in a different way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getInstance` method is a static method of `AbstractManager` class, it does not do anything with instantiated classes. remove the `static`.

Also you do not need the `instance` member.

```
abstract class AbstractManager {

    constructor() {
    }

    public getInstance(): this {
        return this
    }

}

class Manager extends AbstractManager {
    managerTalk() {
        console.log("Hello I am Manager");
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const manager = new Manager();

const instance = manager.getInstance();
console.log(manager.getInstance()) // <--Manager

manager.managerTalk();
instance.managerTalk();
```

Take a look in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20AbstractManager%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getInstance()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Manager%20extends%20AbstractManager%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20managerTalk()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%20I%20am%20Manager%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20manager%20%3D%20new%20Manager()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instance%20%3D%20manager.getInstance()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(manager.getInstance())%20%2F%2F%20%3C--Manager%0D%0A%0D%0Amanager.managerTalk()%3B%0D%0Ainstance.managerTalk()%3B)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the point of the static method is so I can retrieve the same instance of the class. In your solution, the `manager.getInstance()` method still has a return type of `AbstractManager`, not the child type `Manager` in visual studio code.

Comment: @aXises no it is not. Take a look at the link in my updated answer.

Comment: add any instance method to the child class and the typescript playground will also display an error stating that the property does not exist on type `AbstractManager`. I have taken a screenshot since the playground link does not fit here. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/omxVTZ2.jpg)

Comment: @aXises that was my fault, I forgot to remove the `AbstractManager` from the return type of `getInstance` to Typescript got the type wrong (but it was just a compilation issue). Answer updated.

Comment: Great, setting the return type to `this` will also work. Is it possible to set it up a way such that it can be invoked from a static context? This way the same instance can be used and retrieved by using the static `getInstance()` method.

Comment: @aXises that is not possible. The `static` method does not have any way to know if an instance exist unless you create some kind of counter and you store references to your instances there. And even there you would need to search for some kind of key or index.